# Stripe open value subscriptions or product values

Tags: wufoo, stripe-payments

So Stripe support is currently not able to answer my questions. I have a Wufoo form set up and Stripe subscriptions tied to it.  Well I have mapped the product values in the Stripe subscriptions to my form values.

However, I am not looking at an open field for a donation form to let a user define a price.  Stripe support can't seem to find an answer.  My assumption the support staff is combing their documentation and Google to find an answer and they can't, the same as I have.
That said, does anyone know if you can pass an open value to a Stripe subscription.
In essence letting a donor define the price they want to pay monthly.

Answer (score 0):

So I checked with Wufoo and through them, the answer is no. Not right now.  You can not add an open value.  I have seen other systems using Stripe in which they allow open values, which means it is possible, but I guess not through Wufoo and you will probably have to write your own subscription code to handle it.